# Multiline non-compiled attribute in jade

Tags: pug, pugjs

I tried to do so:

```
body(
  |{% case page.url %}
  | {% when '/' %}
  |    class="hellopage"
  | {% when page.url contains '/gallery/' %}
  |    class="gallerypage"
  |{% endcase %}
  )
```

This {% .. %} stuff for Liquid actually.
So, it is not compiled. How can I write a multi-line attribute in tag?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're using a template language on top of a templating language? The `case` statement there could be implemented in pug, as well, removing the need for liquid...

Comment: @gandreadis, Liquid in jekyll. I can not refer to the site url  through the pug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the Pug compiler does not like the `{%` character sequences in the attribute. In your specific scenario, this the work-around would be to escape the newlines and put Liquid logic in the attribute value string, as well:

```
body(class="\
   {% case page.url %}\
    {% when '/' %}\
       hellopage\
    {% when page.url contains '/gallery/' %}\
       gallerypage\
   {% endcase %}"
  )
```

*Old answer:*

I don't think that you need the pipe character (`|`) to do this. Attributes on multiple lines [are supported](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#multiline-attributes) by Pug. Something like this should be sufficient:

```
body(
   {% case page.url %}
    {% when '/' %}
       class="hellopage"
    {% when page.url contains '/gallery/' %}
       class="gallerypage"
   {% endcase %}
  )
```

Should work, but haven't tested it though (due to a lack of a Liquid+Pug testing environment).

Comment: Actually it's not the attribute, this is plain text in attribute... In any case, your guess [does not work](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/21/0001/0403/94611/11/f1cd297b88.png).

Comment: Are you running the liquid compiler before the Pug compiler? Because this looks like the `{%` tags are not correctly removed after liquid is done compiling

Comment: I need compile jade before liquid(jekyll) run itself.

Comment: Well, from what I'm seeing on your screenshot, the gulp compiler simply does not like seeing unknown character sequences (like `{%`) somewhere in attributes. What you could do is use an [unbuffered code snippet](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code) to declare the value of the attribute, and then refer to it in the attributes. I'll update my answer to add that

Comment: Nvm, that wouldn't work either, if the Pug code is compiled first... Is putting everything on one single line a possibility? So `body(class="{% case page.url %}{% when '/' %}hellopage{% when page.url contains '/gallery/' %}gallerypage{% endcase %}")`. Not a clean fix, but should work

Comment: Second tip [really works](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/21/0001/0403/94611/11/4280279b99.png), thanks! But I was faced with another [problem](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/21/0001/0403/94611/11/6bcf56ecf4.png) ...  Can you help her to solve, please?

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly, it would be great if you could mark it as accepted (to help anyone from the wider community who might encounter a similar problem). For your second question, I don't have any direct intuition as to what might be going wrong, but feel free to open a new question here on SO with the [jekyll] tag, maybe someone from that community can help you out :)

Comment: No, it's works. [Look](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/21/0001/0403/94611/11/61e88387c1.png)

Comment: Okay, I will) Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133697/discussion-between-vostoksisters-and-gandreadis).